# Ubuntu Reverse Proxy

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to host a website but in the same time mask my real ip address, I did some researching and found something called Reverse Proxy, I'm not sure if this is what i'm needing so i'll give an example to what i need. For example.com goes to my website but if they do ping example.com i want they don't see my real ip address for security reasons, Is this what a reverse proxy does? will it mask my real ip.
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Reverse_proxy_h2g2bob.svg/2000px-Reverse_proxy_h2g2bob.svg.png

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are asking for, but, assuming example.com has IP A, and your "real" web server has IP B, then a proxy running on IP A could definitely hide (and protect) all direct access to IP B. From the picture you linked to, the Proxy would be IP A, and the Web Server is IP B.

Now, without other protection (e.g. firewall or a private internal network), there's nothing inherently that protects either IP's from ping's or direct access.